# XCode How to create a UIView with a Heart shape? Here is an example of a circle

Tags: xcode, uiview, drawrect, uibezierpath

I need a heart shape UIView, this is an example of a circle same concept! Any idea how I would draw this in the drawRect method?

```
//  CircleView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CircleView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *circleColor;
@property BOOL isFilled;
@end

//  CircleView.m
#import "CircleView.h"
@implementation CircleView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSLog(@"isFilled: %d",_isFilled);
    if(_isFilled) {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, _circleColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx,  CGRectMake( rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y, rect.size.width ,rect.size.height));
    } else {
        CGPoint midPoint = { CGRectGetMidX (rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect) };
        CGFloat radius = (rect.size.width * 0.5)  -2; // * _lineThickness;
        CGContextAddArc (ctx, midPoint.x, midPoint.y, radius, 0, M_PI * 180, NO);
        CGContextSetLineCap (ctx, kCGLineCapSquare );
        CGContextSetLineWidth (ctx, 2.0);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, _circleColor.CGColor);
        CGContextStrokePath (ctx);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath (ctx);
//    [self.circleLabel drawRect:rect];
}
@end
```

So the idea is I would be able to add multiple UIView of type HeartView similar to the previous code for CircleView.